# Encrypted home folder is only partially decrypted by ecryptfs

Tags: encryption, data-recovery, ecryptfs, filename, decryption

I'll make this as brief as possible:

-Following an upgrade, lubuntu no longer boots
-I installed ubuntu gnome on a separate partition
-Within the new partition, I mounted the other (lubuntu) partition and decrypted it using encryptfs as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory and http://www.kaijanmaki.net/2009/10/26/recovering-files-from-ecryptfs-encrypted-home/

The results:

-Most if not all of the folders in /home/ were recovered
-Most but not all of those folders cannot be opened. In the folders that can be opened, all the files and folders are decrypted with their original names.
-There is one folder in /home/ whose name begins with ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED. Inside are two folders with similar names. One of these contains most of my folders and files; all of the files and folders in that folder have ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED prefixes, but the files and folders inside those folders all have their original names.
The other contains about 200 encrypted files, the only encrypted files I could find anywhere, with ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED prefixes.

So nearly all (but not all) of the files decrypted, but many of them are not in their original places and have encrypted filenames.

I tried decrypting just the encrypted folder, but got an error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /home/***/recover/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWab8i5xNy-bDkS7UxwSeMXrBYH7mEizVMTroCYzedp7twnpmpUHyLZOqk--,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
Error mounting eCryptfs: [-1] Operation not permitted
Check your system logs; visit <http://ecryptfs.org/support.html>
```

I've read many threads on similar issues but have yet to find a solution.

Does anyone have any suggestions for recovering these files?

Answer (score 0):

A recovery suggestion: the upgrade sounds like it somehow caused the problems, so try booting from a live iso of your previous Ubuntu version, then try decrypting / recovery with it, possibly using the ecryptfs recovery program (ecryptfs-recover-home I think?).

May have to restore from your backup - should ***always have a backup*** especially with encryption and/or an upgrade.